# Volume projections to plane, cannot run demo code

Tags: plotting

I'm copying the code from [*"New in Mathematica 10 › Basic and Formula Regions"*](https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/basic-and-formula-regions/formula-region-projections.html)

```
ℛ = 
  ImplicitRegion[
   x^6 - 5 x^4 y z + 3 x^4 y^2 + 10 x^2 y^3 z + 3 x^2 y^4 - y^5 z + 
     y^6 + z^6 <= 1, {x, y, z}];

    RegionPlot3D[ℛ, 
     PlotRange -> {{-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.5, 1.5}, {-1.6, 1.6}}, 
     PlotPoints -> 50]

{
 RegionPlot[
  Resolve[Exists[z, {x,y,z} ∈ ℛ], Reals]
  , {x, -1.5, 1.5}
  , {y, -1.5, 1.5}
  ],
 RegionPlot[
  Resolve[Exists[y, {x,y,z} ∈ ℛ], Reals]
  , {x, -1.5, 1.5}
  , {z, -1.5, 1.5}
  ],
 RegionPlot[
  Resolve[Exists[x, {x,y,z} ∈ ℛ], Reals]
  , {y, -1.5, 1.5}
  , {z, -1.5, 1.5}
  ]
 }
```

[image]

It fails (I'm using version 11.3). Also I've heard that using Resolve is slow.

If I want to project a volume on to an arbitrary infinite plane, and observe the result area, what should I do instead?

Comment: Hi seilgu, welcome to Mma.SE. Start by **taking the [tour] now** and learning about [asking](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O) and what's [on-topic](https://wolfr.am/wb2ijD7O). Always [edit] if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. By doing all this you help us to help you and likely you will inspire great answers. I can reproduce your problem, it's not obvious to me what is the case.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me whether this ever worked in any version of Mathematica. At any rate, the issue is that the [`Resolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Resolve) command needs to be evaluated before values for `x` and `y` are inserted.  So, the following produces the output given in the documentation *(albeit with some error messages related to underflow that I quieted)*.

```
Quiet @ {
RegionPlot[
    Evaluate @ Resolve[Exists[z, {x,y,z} ∈ ℛ], Reals],
    {x, -1.5, 1.5},
    {y, -1.5, 1.5}
],
RegionPlot[
    Evaluate @ Resolve[Exists[y, {x,y,z} ∈ ℛ], Reals],
    {x, -1.5, 1.5},
    {z, -1.5, 1.5}
],
RegionPlot[
    Evaluate @ Resolve[Exists[x, {x,y,z} ∈, Reals],
    {y, -1.5, 1.5},
    {z, -1.5, 1.5}
]
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway to find the projected region faster?